# Getting field value from django database

Tags: django

I have an staticmethod where I save user (if exists) and calculation.

```
    @staticmethod
    def save_calculation(user, selection, calculation_data):
        customer = None

        if calculation_data['firstname'] or calculation_data['lastname']:
            customer = Customer()
            customer.title = calculation_data['title']
            customer.firstname = calculation_data['firstname']
            customer.lastname = calculation_data['lastname']
            customer.save()


        n_calculation = Calculations()
        n_calculation.user = user
        n_calculation.category = selection['category_name']
        n_calculation.make = selection['make_name']
        n_calculation.model = selection['model_name']
        n_calculation.purchase_price = selection['purchase_price']
        n_calculation.customer = customer
        n_calculation.save()
        return {'statusCode': 200, 'calculation': n_calculation, 'customer': customer}
```

And the view, where I want to get the results is as follows :

```
def adviced_price(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    connector = Adapter(Connector)
    selection = Selection(request).to_dict()
    calculation = connector.calculations(request.user, selection, request.POST)

    if 'statusCode' in calculation and calculation['statusCode'] == 200:
        customer = ''
        if 'customer' in calculation:
            customer = calculation['customer']

        price = calculation['calculation']['purchase_price'] # How to get the price
        context = {"calculation_data": calculation['calculation'], 'customer': customer, 'price': price}
        return render(request, 'master/result-calculation.html', context)
    else:
        return
else:
    return HttpResponse('Not POST')
```

The calculation which I get in the view is as follows :

```
{'statusCode': 200, 'calculation': <Calculations: Calculation for user>, 'customer': None}
```

How can I now get the `purchase_price` from calculation? I tried with

```
price = calculation['calculation']['purchase_price']
```

But I get an error : `TypeError: 'Calculations' object is not subscriptable`

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning

`{'statusCode': 200, 'calculation': <Calculations: Calculation for user>, 'customer': None}`

and assigning it to `calculation`.
Your `calculation['calculation']` is `Calculation` object which does not have `__getitem__` method, so u can't use it like `dict`.

You should instead do

```
price = calculation['calculation'].purchase_price
```